# Does passport local vs social login change the way cookies are set?

Tags: node.js, express, cookies

I am trying to handle generating tokens and storing them in HttpOnly cookies for authenticating requests between my front(react) and backend(node). I am using Passport for session management/authentication but for some reason setting the cookie with the authtoken only works on the google callback route and not on my local signup route.

This route works flawlessly, sets the cookie and it is available for use.

```
router.get(
    '/google/callback',
    async (req, res, next) => {
        passport.authenticate('google', async (err, user, info) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
                return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
            }

            if (!user) {
                return res.status(401).json({ error: 'Authentication failed', info });
            }

            try {
                const firstSignIn = user.settings.termsAccepted;
                if (!firstSignIn) {
                    // Send account confirmation email
                    const emailSent = await sendEmailConfirmation(user.email, user.name.split(' ')[0]);

                    if (!emailSent) {
                        return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error sending account confirmation email' });
                    }
                }

                req.logIn(user, async (err) => {
                    if (err) {
                        console.error(err);
                        return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
                    }

                    try {
                        checkForFollowUps(res, user);
                        await checkForTasks(user);
                        handleTokenGeneration(req, res, user);
                    } catch (followUpsError) {
                        console.error('Error while checking follow-ups:', followUpsError);
                        return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error checking follow-ups' });
                    }
                });
            } catch (tokenError) {
                console.error('Error obtaining tokens:', tokenError.message);
                return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error during token acquisition' });
            }
        })(req, res, next);
    },
    (req, res) => {
        if (!req.user) {
            return res.status(401).json({ error: 'Authentication failed' });
        }
    }
);
```

This route does not, the cookie never gets set.

```
router.post('/signup', async (req, res, next) => {
    const { name, email, password } = req.body;

    if (!email || !password) {
        return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Email and password are required for signup.' });
    }

    try {
        const existingUser = await getUserByEmail(email);

        if (existingUser) {
            return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Email already in use' });
        }

        const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);

        // Password Validation
        const minLength = 8;
        const hasLetter = /[a-zA-Z]/.test(password);
        const hasNumber = /\d/.test(password);
        const hasSpecialChar = /[^a-zA-Z0-9]/.test(password);

        if (!(password.length >= minLength && hasLetter && hasNumber && hasSpecialChar)) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                error:
                    'Invalid password. Please ensure it has at least 8 characters and includes letters, numbers, and at least one special character',
            });
        }

        const newUser = new User({
            name: name,
            email: email,
            password: hashedPassword,
        });

        await newUser.save();

        // Send account confirmation email using the utility function
        const emailSent = await sendEmailConfirmation(email, name);

        if (!emailSent) {
            console.log('failed to send confirmation email');
        }
        // Manually log in the user after signup
        req.logIn(newUser, (err) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
                return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
            }

            handleTokenGeneration(req, res, newUser);
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
    }
});
```

This is the token generation logic.

```
const handleTokenGeneration = (req, res, user) => {
    const token = jwt.sign({ userId: user.id, email: user.email }, secretKey, { expiresIn: '7d' });

    res.cookie('authToken', token, {
        maxAge: 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
        httpOnly: true,
    });

    res.redirect(`http://localhost:3005/dashboard`);
};
```

If there is an all together better way to deal with this, I'm all ears. This is just the way the applications I work with day to day manage it.